# From Mac OS X 10.6.7 to latest version of MAC OS X

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have recently updated xcode to 4.4.1 .  But it says, an update of Mac OSX  is required. I am having 10.6.7 presently. What is the latest version of Mac OSX i can download ? Is MAC OSX mountain lion is the latest version ( 10.8.2 ) ?

Comment: yes latest version is 10.8.0 Mountain lion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Mountain Lion 10.8 is the current version of MAC OS X

See [OSX Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X)

See [Apple upgrade guide](http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/)

As you can see you will need to have one of this models to upgrade

- iMac (Mid 2007 or newer)
- MacBook (Late 2008 Aluminum, or Early 2009 or newer)
- MacBook Pro (Mid/Late 2007 or newer) MacBook Air (Late 2008or newer)
- Mac mini (Early 2009 or newer) Mac Pro (Early 2008 or newer)
- Xserve (Early 2009)

Answer (score 0):

Yes Mac OS X mountain lion (10.8.2) (and some minor updates) is latest version

Comment: And I believe you need to pay to get the update..